# How to know if images failed to load in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, web

Is there any way to know that some images have failed to load in a web page in jquery/javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use: ***[.error()](http://api.jquery.com/error/)***

```
$('img').error(function() {
  alert('Failed to load the image with src: ' + $(this).attr('src'));
});
```